# Python | Как найти индекс символа в строке?

Tags: python

Как не используя `str.find` и `index(input)` найти индекс подстроки в строке?

Comment: Короткий ответ - циклом. Что вы сами пробовали делать и что у вас не получилось? И определитесь, вам символ в строке нужно найти (как в заголовке) или подстроку в строке (как в самом вопросе)?

Comment: индекс символа простым циклом находится, но [чтобы найти индекс подстроки существуют интересные алгоритмы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8), которые могут улучшить `O(n*k)` сложность для типичного ввода.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Используйте index `string.index(s, sub[, start[, end]])` - [оффициальная документация](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)

```
>>> myString = 'aaaaSbbb'
>>> myString.index('S')
4
```

Comment: В вопросе явно указано "не используя find и index", так что ответ совсем не в тему.

Answer (score 1):

Учтите, что нумерация будет идти с нуля

```
text='bla-bla-this-bla'
subtext='a'

result = []

flag = False
n = 1

for i,element in enumerate(text):
    if flag:
        if n > len(subtext)-1:
            flag = False
            n = 1
        elif element == subtext[n]:
            n += 1
        elif element != subtext[n]:
            result = result[:-1]
            n = 1
            flag = False
    if element == subtext[0] and not flag:
        flag = True
        result.append(i)

for item in result:
    print('Вхождение с ' + str(item) + ' символа')
```

Comment: `if element == subtext[0]:` можно убрать. Сложность алгоритма это не улучшает.

Comment: Нет, убрать нельзя, т.к. если Вы проанализируете алгоритм внимательнее, то заметите, что сравнивается только первый символ, а далее уже вся подстрока. При больших объёмах это будет серьёзная экономия времени и нагрузки на CPU.

Comment: *"Сложность алгоритма это не улучшает"*—если вы уберёте `if element = subtext[0]`, то сложность по прежнему будет `O(n*m)`. Если вы думаете, что на практике `if element` делает код быстрее, то это вероятно, но в этом случае следует указывать benchmark, который вы использовали для сравнения (конкретную реализацию (например, на pypy, я бы попробовал: `for j, c in enumerate(subtext): if text[i + j] != c: break # unequal ..`), ожидаемый ввод (размер, частоты символов) итд).

Comment: И почему же n*m?

Comment: Пример: `text="a"*n;  subtext="ab"` (m=2). Если это не очевидно, то задайте в виде отдельного вопроса.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/513564/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0

Comment: А как Вам этот алгоритм?

Comment: для целей данного вопроса, я бы сперва привёл самый простой (читаемый) алгоритм (какой он у вас был изначально —минус `if element` часть). Можно конечно и более сложные алгоритмы приводить, если указать в чём их достоинство и на какие случаи они рассчитаны (посмотрите ссылку на Википедия под вопросом, в которой упомянуты несколько алгоритмов) .

Comment: @RemiZOffAlex, Спасибо помог. Очень полезный код сейчас буду разбираться