# Какова сложность алгоритма и как она подсчитана?

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x

Какова сложность алгоритма поиска подстроки в строке, и как она подсчитана? Прошу объяснить. (алгоритм сыроват, но упрощён в качестве примера и для понимания)

```
text='bla-bla-this-bla'
subtext='this'
for i,element in enumerate(text):
    if element == subtext[0]:
        if subtext == text[i:i+len(subtext)]:
            print(i)
```

Answer (score 4):

Пусть:

```
n = len(text)
m = len(subtext)
```

Очевидно что цикл `for` сделает в худшем случае `n` итераций, внутри каждой итерации в худшем случае мы делаем слайс `text[i:i+len(subtext)]`, который выполняется за [O(m)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), а затем сравнение за те же O(m), в итоге получаем O(nm).

Comment: m константа, она отбрасывается

Comment: @Komdosh ну не факт, подстрока ведь может быть сопоставимой длины со строкой

Comment: но мы же по ней в цикле не бежим, только по text

Comment: @Komdosh напрямую нет, но ведь мы делаем слайс `text[i:i+len(subtext)]`, сложность которого как раз завязана на длину подстроки, плюс сравнение `subtext == text[i:i+len(subtext)]` не за константное время выполняется.

Comment: @Komdosh Тогда, рассуждая по-вашему, и `n` - константа :) Ведь мы берем конкретную строку? :)